# Como mudar o Índice do ListBox para 1?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

> Citação

Gostaria de adicionar nomes em um `listbox`, coloquei um `NumericUpDown` para associar quantos nomes de dependentes serão no máximo adicionados, dependendo do número que o usuário digitar, e um `txtbox` para ser adicionado os nomes e um botão para adicionar no `listbox`, como posso fazer para que se no caso for colocado 0 dependentes não poderá ser adicionado nenhum nome, e se for colocado um valor maior por exemplo 2 poderá ser adicionado somente 2 nomes no `listbox`.

Tentei assim, mas não deu certo:

```
private void btn_AdcNomedep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (numUpDown_Dependentes.Value > 0 && numUpDown_Dependentes.Value >= listbox_NomesDep.Items.Count)
    {
        if (!listbox_NomesDep.Items.Contains(tb_NomeDep.Text))
        {
            listbox_NomesDep.Items.Add(tb_NomeDep.Text);
            tb_NomeDep.Clear();
            tb_NomeDep.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item já existente!", "Erro!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            tb_NomeDep.Clear();
            tb_NomeDep.Focus();
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("O número de dependentes já foi preenchido!", tb_NomeDep.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não disse ao certo qual erro ou problema você está tendo.
Eu simulei o seu código aqui do meu lado e o unico erro que encontrei foi que essa condição permite que você adicione um item a mais no listBox

```
if (numUpDown_Dependentes.Value > 0 && numUpDown_Dependentes.Value >= listbox_NomesDep.Items.Count)
```

Condição correta para permitir o mesmo valor do contador

```
if (numUpDown_Dependentes.Value > 0 && numUpDown_Dependentes.Value > listbox_NomesDep.Items.Count)
```

Outro detalhe seria impedir que o usuário diminua a contagem sem antes de remover um item da lista. o código a seguir é um evento `ValueChanged` do `NumericUpDown`

```
//Verifica se o valor do contador é menor que os itens da lista
private void numUpDown_Dependentes_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var nud = sender as NumericUpDown;

   if(nud.Value < listbox_NomesDep.Items.Count)
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Você não pode diminuir a contagem sem antes remover um departamento cadastrado!");
       numUpDown_Dependentes.Value = listbox_NomesDep.Items.Count;
   }
}
```

E não pode esquecer também de permitir que remova o item da lista e ao mesmo tempo diminua o valor do contador.
O código a seguir é um evento de `MouseClick` do `ListBox`

```
private void listbox_NomesDep_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //seleciona o valor que o usuario clicou
    var selectedItem = listbox_NomesDep.SelectedItem;
    if(selectedItem != null)
    {
        //remove da lista
        listbox_NomesDep.Items.Remove(selectedItem);
        //diminui 1 do contador
        numUpDown_Dependentes.Value -= 1;
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.